# OpenMP threads not activating when run with mpirun

Tags: mpi, openmp

While trying to run a hybrid MPI/OpenMP application I realized that the number of OpenMP threads was always 1, even though I exported `OMP_NUM_THREAS=36`. I build a small C++ example showing the issue:

```
#include <vector>
#include "math.h"

int main ()
{
    int n=4000000,  m=1000;
    double x=0,y=0;
    double s=0;
    std::vector< double > shifts(n,0);


    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x,y)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {

        double r=0.0;
        for (int i=0; i < m; i++){

            double rand_g1 = cos(i/double(m));
            double rand_g2 = sin(i/double(m));

            x += rand_g1;
            y += rand_g2;
            r += sqrt(rand_g1*rand_g1 + rand_g2*rand_g2);
        }
        shifts[j] = r / m;
    }
}
```

I compile the code using `g++`:

```
g++ -fopenmp main.cpp
```

`OMP_NUM_THREADS` is still set to 36. When I run the code with just:

```
time ./a.out
```

I get a run-time of about 6 seconds and `htop` shows the command using all 36 cores of my local node, as expected. When I run it with `mpirun`:

```
time mpirun -np 1 ./a.out
```

I get a run-time of 3m20s and `htop` shows the command is using only on one core. I've also tried using `mpirun -np 1 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=36 ./a.out` but results were the same.

I am using GCC 9.2.0 and OpenMPI 4.1.0a1. Since this is a developer version, I've also tried with OpenMPI 4.0.3 with the same result.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Maybe this can add some further insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944979/7678171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of Open MPI is to

- bind a MPI task on a core if there are two or less MPI tasks
- bind a MPI task to a socket otherwise

So you really should

```
mpirun --bind-to none -np 1 ./a.out
```

so your MPI task can access all the cores of your host.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue. I did not mention this but a few months ago hybrid MPI/OpenMP was working fine without that flag (I think with version 3.x). Is the default to bind MPI task to core a new feature in 4.x?

Comment: IIRC, 3.x has the same behavior with respect to binding.