# Why openmp 32 thread is much slower than 1 thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I am trying to write an application calculating l2 norm of 2 arrays. I have to parallel my calculation.

Here is the code that I have parallelized:

```
  double time_start_openmp = omp_get_wtime();
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
       numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
       double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
       diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
       l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
  }

   time_end_openmp = omp_get_wtime();

   l2_norm = sqrt(l2_norm);

   openmp_exec_time = time_end_openmp - time_start_openmp;
   printf("OPENMP: %d %ld %f %.12e\n", n, numberOfThreads, openmp_exec_time, l2_norm);
```

I compile the code as:

```
gcc -fopenmp -g -ggdb -Wall -lm -o test test.c
```

I am running this code with 1 threads and 32 threads. The output is the exact opposite of what's expected. Here is an example output:

```
[hayri@hayri-durmaz MatrixMultipication_MPI]$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=32
[hayri@hayri-durmaz MatrixMultipication_MPI]$ ./test 10000
OPENMP: 10000 32 0.001084 0.000000000000e+00
[hayri@hayri-durmaz MatrixMultipication_MPI]$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
[hayri@hayri-durmaz MatrixMultipication_MPI]$ ./test 10000
OPENMP: 10000 1 0.000106 0.000000000000e+00
```

Am I seeing wrong or using 32 threads is 10 times slower than 1 thread? So, what am I doing wrong here?

Here is my full code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MATSIZE 2000

static size_t totalMemUsage = 0;

size_t vectors_dot_prod(double *x, double *y, size_t n)
{
    double res = 0.0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        res += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return res;
}

size_t vectors_dot_prod2(double *x, double *y, size_t n)
{
    size_t res = 0.0;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (; i <= n - 4; i += 4)
    {
        res += (x[i] * y[i] +
                x[i + 1] * y[i + 1] +
                x[i + 2] * y[i + 2] +
                x[i + 3] * y[i + 3]);
    }
    for (; i < n; i++)
    {
        res += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return res;
}

void matrix_vector_mult(double **mat, double *vec, double *result, size_t rows, size_t cols)
{ // in matrix form: result = mat * vec;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = vectors_dot_prod2(mat[i], vec, cols);
    }
}

double get_random()
{

    double range = 1000;
    double div = RAND_MAX / range;
    double randomNumber = (rand() / div);
    // printf("%d\n", randomNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}

void print_2d_arr(double *arr, size_t row, size_t col)
{
    size_t i, j, index;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            index = i * col + j;
            printf("%3f ", arr[index]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void print_1d_arr(double *arr, size_t row)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        printf("%f, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

size_t **fullfillArrayWithRandomNumbers(double *arr, size_t n)
{
    /*
    * Fulfilling the array with random numbers 
    * */
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = get_random();
    }
    return 0;
}

double *allocarray1D(size_t size)
{
    double *array = calloc(size, sizeof(double));
    totalMemUsage = totalMemUsage + size * sizeof(double);
    return array;
}

size_t ParallelRowMatrixVectorMultiply(size_t n, double *a, double *b, double *x, MPI_Comm comm)
{
    size_t i, j;
    size_t nlocal;
    double *fb;
    int npes, myrank;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &npes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    fb = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    nlocal = n / npes;
    MPI_Allgather(b, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, fb, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, comm);
    for (i = 0; i < nlocal; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            size_t index = i * n + j;
            x[i] += a[index] * fb[j];
        }
    }
    free(fb);
    return 0;
}

size_t ParallelRowMatrixVectorMultiply_WithoutAllgather(size_t n, double *a, double *b, double *x_partial, double *x, MPI_Comm comm)
{

    // Process 0 sends b to everyone
    MPI_Bcast(b, n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    size_t i, j;
    size_t nlocal;
    // double *fb;
    int npes, myrank;
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &npes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    // fb = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    nlocal = n / npes;
    // MPI_Allgather(b, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, fb, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, comm);
    for (i = 0; i < nlocal; i++)
    {
        x_partial[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            size_t index = i * n + j;
            // printf("%f x %f\n", a[index], b[j]);
            x_partial[i] += a[index] * b[j];
        }
    }
    // free(b);

    // Process 0 gathers x_partials to create x
    MPI_Gather(x_partial, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, x, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    return 0;
}

size_t SequentialMatrixMultiply(size_t n, double *a, double *b, double *x)
{
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            size_t index = i * n + j;
            // printf("%f x %f\n", a[index], b[j]);
            x[i] += a[index] * b[j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Global declerations
    size_t i;
    // MPI_Status status;

    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int taskid;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        if (taskid == 0)
            printf("Usage: %s <N>\n", argv[0]);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
    srand(time(NULL) + taskid);
    size_t n = atoi(argv[1]);
    size_t nOverK = n / world_size;

    double *a = allocarray1D(n * n);
    double *b = allocarray1D(n);
    double *x = allocarray1D(n);
    double *x_partial = allocarray1D(nOverK);
    double *xseq = allocarray1D(n);

    double *a_partial = allocarray1D(n * nOverK);

    if (a == NULL || b == NULL || x == NULL || xseq == NULL || x_partial == NULL)
    {
        if (taskid == 0)
            printf("Allocation failed\n");
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
    // Process 0 creates A matrix.
    if (taskid == 0)
    {
        fullfillArrayWithRandomNumbers(a, n * n);
        // Process 0 produces the b
        fullfillArrayWithRandomNumbers(b, n);
    }

    // Process 0 sends a_partial to everyone
    if (!(world_size == 1 && n == 64000))
    {
        MPI_Scatter(a, n * nOverK, MPI_DOUBLE, a_partial, n * nOverK, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double time_start = MPI_Wtime();
    ParallelRowMatrixVectorMultiply_WithoutAllgather(n, a_partial, b, x_partial, x, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double time_end = MPI_Wtime();
    double parallel_exec_time = time_end - time_start;

    double *exec_times = allocarray1D(world_size);
    // Process 0 gathers x_partials to create x
    MPI_Gather(&parallel_exec_time, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, exec_times, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // print_1d_arr(x, n);

    if (taskid == 0)
    {
        SequentialMatrixMultiply(n, a, b, xseq);
        // check difference between x and xseq using OpenMP
        //print_1d_arr(exec_times, world_size);
        // print_1d_arr(xseq, n);
        double max_exec, min_exec, avg_exec;
        min_exec = 1000;
        for (i = 0; i < world_size; i++)
        {
            if (max_exec < exec_times[i])
            {
                max_exec = exec_times[i];
            }
            if (min_exec > exec_times[i])
            {
                min_exec = exec_times[i];
            }
            avg_exec += exec_times[i];
        }
        avg_exec = avg_exec / world_size;

        long double time_start_openmp = omp_get_wtime();
        long double time_end_openmp, openmp_exec_time, min_exec_time, max_exec_time, avg_exec_time;
        max_exec_time = 0;
        max_exec_time = 1000;
        long double l2_norm = 0;
        size_t numberOfThreads = 0;
        size_t r = 0;
        double *diff_vector = allocarray1D(n);
        size_t nrepeat = 10000;

        if (world_size == 1)
        {
            #pragma omp parallel
            {
                numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
                    diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
                    l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            #pragma omp parallel
            {
                numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
                    diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
                    l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
                }
            }
        }
        l2_norm = sqrt(l2_norm);
        time_end_openmp = omp_get_wtime();
        openmp_exec_time = time_end_openmp - time_start_openmp;
        // print matrix size, number of processors, number of threads, time, time_openmp, L2 norm of difference of x and xseq (use %.12e while printing norm)
        if (world_size == 1)
        {
            printf("OPENMP: %d %ld %Lf %.12e\n", n, numberOfThreads, openmp_exec_time, openmp_exec_time, l2_norm);
            printf("NEW_OPENMP: %d %ld %f %.12e\n", n, numberOfThreads, openmp_exec_time, l2_norm);
        }
        printf("MIN_AVG_MAX: %d %d %f %f %f\n", n, world_size, min_exec, max_exec, avg_exec);
        printf("MPI: %d %d %f %.12Lf %.12e\n", n, world_size, max_exec, l2_norm, l2_norm);
        totalMemUsage = totalMemUsage / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        printf("TOTALMEMUSAGE: %zu\n", totalMemUsage);

        //printf("process: %d %d %d %f %.12e\n", taskid, n, world_size, parallel_exec_time, l2_norm);
        //printf("%d %ld %f %.12e\n", n, numberOfThreads, openmp_exec_time, l2_norm);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output;

```
cn009
36
mpicc -fopenmp -g -ggdb  -lm -o rowmv rowmv.c 


OPENMP: 32000 1 0.000299 2.991110086441e-04
MIN_AVG_MAX: 32000 1 3.112523 3.112523 3.112523
MPI: 32000 1 3.112523 0.000000000000 9.532824124368e-130
TOTALMEMUSAGE: 15


OPENMP: 32000 2 0.000535 5.350699648261e-04
MIN_AVG_MAX: 32000 1 3.125519 3.125519 3.125519
MPI: 32000 1 3.125519 0.000000000000 9.532824124368e-130
TOTALMEMUSAGE: 15


OPENMP: 32000 4 0.000434 4.341900348663e-04
MIN_AVG_MAX: 32000 1 3.170650 3.170650 3.170650
MPI: 32000 1 3.170650 0.000000000000 9.532824124368e-130
TOTALMEMUSAGE: 15


OPENMP: 32000 8 0.000454 4.542167298496e-04
MIN_AVG_MAX: 32000 1 3.168685 3.168685 3.168685
MPI: 32000 1 3.168685 0.000000000000 9.532824124368e-130
TOTALMEMUSAGE: 15


OPENMP: 32000 16 0.000507 5.065393634140e-04
MIN_AVG_MAX: 32000 1 3.158761 3.158761 3.158761
MPI: 32000 1 3.158761 0.000000000000 9.532824124368e-130
TOTALMEMUSAGE: 15


OPENMP: 32000 32 0.000875 8.752988651395e-04
MIN_AVG_MAX: 32000 1 3.166051 3.166051 3.166051
MPI: 32000 1 3.166051 0.000000000000 9.532824124368e-130
TOTALMEMUSAGE: 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I seeing wrong or using 32 threads is 10 times slower than 1
> thread? So, what am I doing wrong here?

In the portion of code that is being both profiled and parallelized with OpenMP:

```
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
    numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
        diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
        l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
    }
 }
```

there is a race condition, namely the access to the variable `l2_norm`. Moreover, you can drop the `private(i)`, since the *index* variable (*i.e.,* `i`) in the parallelized loop will be set implicitly as *private* by OpenMP. The race condition can be fixed with the OpenMP *reduction*. Furthermore, your loop is not actually distributing the iterations among threads as you wanted. Because you added again the **parallel** clause to that `#pragma omp for`, and assuming that you have nested parallelism disabled, which by default it is, each of the threads created in the outer `parallel region` will execute *"sequentially"* the code within that region, namely:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
        diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
        l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
    }
```

Hence, each thread will execute all the `N` iterations of the loop that you intended to be parallelized. Consequently, removing the parallelism and adding additional overhead (*e.g.,* thread creation) to the sequential code. To fix those problems (*i.e.,* race condition and *"nested"* parallel region) change this code to:

```
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
    numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    #pragma omp for reduction(+:l2_norm)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
        diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
        l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
    }
 }
```

Now, having fixed those problems you are left still with another problem (performance-wise),  namely that the parallel loop is being performed in the context of a hybrid parallelization of `OpenMP + MPI`, and **you did not explicitly** bind the `OpenMP` threads (within the `MPI` processes) to the corresponded cores. Without that explicit binding, one cannot be sure in which cores those threads will end up. Naturally, more often than not, having multiple threads running in the same *logical* core will increase the overall execution of the application being parallelized.

If your application uses threads, then you probably want to ensure that you are either not bound at all (by specifying --bind-to none), or bound to multiple cores using an appropriate binding level or a specific number of processing elements *per* application process. You can solve this problem by either:

1. disabling the binding with the MPI flag `--bind-to none`, to enable threads to be assigned to different cores;
2. or perform the bound of threads, accordingly. Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821498/ensure-hybrid-mpi-openmp-runs-each-openmp-thread-on-a-different-core) on how to map the threads to cores in Hybrid parallelizations such as `MPI + OpenMP`.

By explicitly setting the number of threads *per* process accordingly, you can avoid that multiple threads end up in the same core, and consequently, avoid that threads within the same core *fight* for the *same* resources.

**Advice:**

IMO you should first test the performance of the `OpenMP` alone, without any MPI process. In this context, test the scalability of code by measuring the sequential version against `2` threads, then `4`, `8`, and so on, gradually increasing the number of threads. Eventually, there will be a number of threads for which the code simply stops scaling. Naturally, the amount of parallel work being performed by the threads has to be big enough to overcome the overhead of parallelism. Therefore, you should also test around with bigger and bigger inputs.

After having profiled, tested an improved your `OpenMP` version you can then extent that shared-memory parallelization with multiple processes using `MPI`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the race condition in updating a shared variable as noted in @dreamcrash's answer, your code is not distributing the work properly.

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
    numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
                ~~~~~~~~
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
        diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
        l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
    }
}
```

The `parallel` construct in the inner loop makes it a nested combined parallel `for` construct. It means that each thread in the team executing the outer parallel loop spawns a brand new parallel region and distributes the `i`-loop over the threads in it. There is **no distribution happening in the outer parallel region** and you end up with *N* threads all repeating the exact same work. By default nested parallelism is disabled, so the nested parallel region runs sequentially and your code is effectively doing this:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
    numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
        diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
        l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
    }
}
```

There is no distribution of work and all threads write to the same locations in the `diff_vector[]` array.

On one hand, this code in general is a memory-bound one since the amount of computation per byte of data is low - modern CPUs can do many multiplications and subtractions per cycle while fetching data from memory and writing results back there takes many cycles. Memory-bound problems don't get any faster with more threads since the limiting factor is the memory bandwidth. This isn't that big of a problem in your case because 32K array entries take up 256 KB of memory and that fits in most CPU caches, and the L3 cache is blazing fast, but is still larger than the fastest L1 cache of a single CPU core. On the other hand, writing to the same memory areas from multiple threads results in true and false sharing, with the associated inter-thread cache invalidation, which usually results in the parallel code running way slower than the sequential version.

There are tools that can help you analyse the performance of your code and spot problems. As I already wrote in a comment, Intel VTune is one of them and is freely available as part of the oneAPI toolkit. Intel Inspector is another one (again, free and part of the oneAPI toolkit) and it finds problems such as data races. The two tools work very well together and I couldn't recommend them strongly enough to any aspiring parallel programmer.

There is also a minor race condition writing to `numberOfThreads`, but since all values written are the same, that isn't much of a logical problem. The correct version of the code in question should be:

```c
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp master
    numberOfThreads = omp_get_num_threads();

    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:l2_norm)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double local_diff = x[i] - xseq[i];
        diff_vector[i] = local_diff;
        l2_norm += (local_diff * local_diff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why add an overhead of the constructor #pragma omp single of the number of threads there is no race condition there, since there is a barrier at the end of the parallel region

Comment: Indeed, `single` is an overkill when `master` would do too.

Comment: I am not debating this statement "Memory-bound problems don't get any faster with more threads since the limiting factor is the memory bandwidth." since you have more experience than I in HPC. But if my memory does not betray me, I recall having a memory-bound algorithm that had gains with hyper threading, I am of the impression that while some of threads where waiting for memory to be fetch the others where busy doing computation. But I might be just wrong

Comment: @dreamcrash that's exactly what I wrote in my comment addressing Matthieu's comment. But it only applies as long as the bandwidth is not completely saturated. Streaming kernels usually reach saturation with a couple of threads, depending on where data lives, and throwing 32 threads at it simply doesn't bring anything useful.